# building a distance matrix from a list of locations

Tags: python, matrix, distance

I have a text file with different cities and specific `la`t and `long` values, and code that can take an initial origin location and destination location and return the distance between the two points using `Google maps API`. What I'm struggling with is how to then build a distance matrix that looks like this:

```
x             loc1    loc2   loc3       ...

loc1 [0              3           4]

loc2      [5              0           7]

loc3      [9              2           0]

....
```

with the text file looking like this:

```
location1, lat1, long1

location2  lat2, long2

location3, lat3, long3
```

any suggestions on how to approach this? I feel like I'm making it more complicated than it has to be. I thought of just iterating a loop where it takes the first location then runs through all other locations, and appends the first line to the end before looping back to the beginning. This assumes knowledge of the number of lines in the text file, which is fine, but then it'd be a hassle to restructure the resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer I was looking for, in case anyone is curious.

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ANSWER:

So you have a list of zip(n) where n = 1...N

Each zip(n) contains a lat value and long value - say zip(n).lat = 44.22; zip(n).long = 39.17

The matrix of distances would then be M(N,N) - a square matrix where the diagonal is always 0 since the distance from zip(n) == zip(n). Further, the upper half of the matrix is the same as the lower half. Meaning zip1 to zipX is the same as zipX to zip1. Thus you only need to calculate 1/2 the matrix - excluding the diagonal. You can use that as a error check.

his code was rather messy and not in python, but the logical process is still the same, which is what I was stuck on. I pasted his code below if people are interested in it (written in java)

The for loops are:

```
Map<int,int> M = new HashMap<int,int>(); - in Java all values are initialized to 0 for you; index goes from 0...N-1

for (int r  = 1; r < N-1; r++) {    // Skip the two corners (0,0) and (N-1,N-1) which are 0
    for (int c = r + 1; c < N; c++) {
        M(r,c) = getDistance(zip(r),zip(c));
    };    // end for c
};    // end for r

You can also use an Map of Integers where the key is the string r+","+c

Map<String,Integer> M = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (int r  = 1; r < N-1; r++) {    // Skip the two corners (0,0) and (N-1,N-1) which are 0
    M.put(r+","+r,new Integer(0));    // diagonal
    for (int c = r + 1; c < N; c++) {
        M.put(r+","+c,new Integer(getDistance(zip(r),zip(c)));    // Upper half
        M.put(c+","+r,new Integer(getDistance(zip(r),zip(c)));    // Lower half
    };    // end for c
};    // end for r
M.put("0,0",new Integer(0));    // upper left corner
M.put((N-1)+","+(N-1),new Integer(0));    // lower right corner
```

Comment: All lovely, but this isn't Python :P